# Swift voting system incrementing and decrementing by 2 instead of 1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a voting system that I implemented in my app. When the user upvotes or downvotes the incrementation works fine, however when they decide to change their vote. One is meant to increase by 1 whilst the other decrements by 1. However I noticed that when the user changes their vote, it increments by 2 on either side and not by one. I'm guessing either runs twice causing this happen but I don't know where in my code that this is happening. I've posted my code below whereby the user decides to change their vote.

```
//User wants to change vote
   else {
        
        // UpVote button
        switch buttonVote {
        case 1 :
            
            if userVotedUP == true {
                //Do nothing
                print("User already voted up")
            }
            else if userVotedUP == false {
                
                //change vote from dislike to like
                self.VoteUpCount  += 1
                self.VoteDownCount -= 1
                
                
                //Reset flags
                self.userVotedUP = true
                self.userVotedDown = false
                
                //Write multiple votes to Firebase
                ref.updateChildValues(["\(atmkind)/\(uid)/votesUpCount": self.VoteUpCount,
                                       "\(atmkind)/\(uid)/votesDownCount": self.VoteDownCount])
                
            }
            
            //DownVote Button
            case -1 :
            
            if userVotedDown == true {
                //Do nothing
                print("User already voted up")
            }
            else if userVotedDown == false {
                
                //change vote from like to dislike
                self.VoteUpCount  -= 1
                self.VoteDownCount += 1
                
                //Reset flags
                self.userVotedUP = false
                self.userVotedDown = true
                
                //Write multiple votes to Firebase
                ref.updateChildValues(["\(atmkind)/\(uid)/votesUpCount": self.VoteUpCount,
                                       "\(atmkind)/\(uid)/votesDownCount": self.VoteDownCount])
                
            }
        default:
            print("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874748/my-swift-voting-system-increments-oddly-in-firebase?noredirect=1#comment114698871_64874748) just to post almost the same one again?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I solved part of the other question, this one is focused on one thing? what should I rather have done?

Comment: Ok but they are posted so close together I don’t see how you had time to properly investigate the changes in that time. Anyway this question suffers from the same problem as the previous, it is impossible to know what happens outside of the code posted in the question to all the class properties you use.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I reviewed my code closely, I put up a question but still try figure it out on my own and I did. Turns out I had to remove one one of the VotersUpCount increments and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at fieldValue increments shown in this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters#swift).

You could implement something like this, lifted from the doc;

```
func incrementCounter(ref: DocumentReference) {

    let docRef = ref.collection("XXXX").document("XXXX")

    docRef.updateData([
        "count": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
    ])
}
```